# On Connection or disconnection Callbacks(listerners)

Tags: go, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I am work on the IOT device where it uses the BLE as the Bluetooth. Where The code was written in the GoLang. I am looking for the Callbacks. Here is the below module I am using for the BLE connection.

In the Go-Bluetooth. Github repo Link: https://github.com/muka/go-bluetooth

Does we have any callback/listeners on connection establishment or on disconnect?

I am unable to find the callback for the event on connection establishment and disconnection from BLE.

Comment: Thanks @ukBaz but we are not using the beacon. But we got to know that Watch Properties is the function which can be used. But my problem was the from which function we can call this watch properties.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I have a partial solution for this.

The way to check this will be through GO Channels. The "Adapter" type has a method to generate a channel that will activate any time any of the properties are changed. You can use this to watch the properties of the devices connected to you, especially the "Connected" property.

1. Get your Adapter by using the GetAdapter method

   ```
    myAdapter := myApp.GetAdapter()
   ```

   myApp is the name of the App you must have created by calling service.NewApp(options)
2. Get the list of devices registered to your adapter.

   ```
    myDeviceList, _ := myAdapter.GetDevices()
   ```

   This will return a list of ALL the devices that have ever connected to your adapter. So don't be surprised if you only have one device connected and this list populates with more than one.
3. Find which device is actually connected by going through the list of devices and see which one has the "Connected" property set to true. Get the channel for that device.

   ```
    for _, device:= range myDeviceList {
        if device.Properties.Connected == true {
            myChannel := device.WatchProperties()
        }
    }
   ```
4. Just watch for that channel. Just remember that it will trigger when ANY property changes, so you must manually look into the "Connected" property to see when it changes to false.

   ```
    go func() {
        for {
            <-myChannel
             print("Something changed!! Ahhhhhh Panic!!\n")
         }
    }()
   ```

I'm also starting with BLE in GO, so this might not be the best solution, but it might work in the meantime and give you some ideas for a better way to do it.